# Importing .bak MySQL database with Python using pymssql

Tags: python, sql, pymssql

The title is pretty self explanotory.

I've tried the following code :

```
import _mssql

conn = _mssql.connect(server='', user='', password='', database='')
conn.execute_non_query("IF EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'mydb') BEGIN ALTER DATABASE mydb MODIFY NAME = mydb_old END")
conn.execute_non_query("RESTORE DATABASE mydb FROM DISK='C:\mydb.bak'")
```

But I get the following error : **No module named '_mssql'**.
I have the version 2.2.2 of pymssql and I use Python 3.9.

I'm just trying to write and read from this database, and I only have the .bak file. I'm quite new to SQL, so I might be doing it the wrong way ? I only have a .bak file though, nothing else.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you trying to restore the DB to a SQLServer database?

Comment: If all else fails you can always resort to looking at the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html

Comment: I don't really know what I'm doing to be honest. The manual you're referring to and all the other documentations I've looked at always have a username and a password which I don't have because I only have a .bak file.

Comment: You missed the point, `_mssql` is the connector to get to a SQLServer (Microsoft) database and NOT a MySQL server database

Comment: @RiggsFolly .bak files are backup files for ms sql server, the restore sql statements in the source code are also for ms sql. The OP just mixed up mysql with ms sql.

Comment: MySQL <> MS SQL. Refine the tags list.

Comment: Can someone explain me the difference? I'm a bit confused, sorry :/

Comment: I changed the tags list. Found out on my own the difference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments:

- MySQL <> MS SQL
- And I have to fill the server = "", user = "", etc ...